# php storing variables for use outside a for loop

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

I have the following for loop:

```
<?php foreach($this->relatedItems as $key=>$item): ?>
<div class="column1"><?php echo $item->extraFields->field1->value; ?></div>
<div class="column2"><?php echo $item->extraFields->field2->value; ?></div>
<div class="column3"><?php echo $item->extraFields->field3->value; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Id like to create a variable for each custom field for each related item passed, for use outside of the loop.

Ideally I would have variables:

relatedItems1_field1,
relatedItems1_field2,
relatedItems1_field3,
relatedItems1_field4,
relatedItems2_field1,
relatedItems2_field2,
relatedItems2_field3,
relatedItems2_field4,
relatedItems3_field1,
relatedItems3_field2,
relatedItems3_field3,
relatedItems3_field4

Any assistance would be much appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you already have those values in the `$this->relatedItems` list? Something like: `$this->relatedItems[0]->extraFields->field1->value` ... etc?

Comment: The output printed in each new line is inside the loop? 
The values will end with 4 each time?

Comment: Hi Magnus, Yes but they end when the loop go's again.

Hi Megan, Yes this output is inside the loop but I also need to use the variables outside the loop. The relateditems and field values will go upto 10.

Comment: Ending with 4 ? relatedItems3_field4 , relatedItems2_field4

Comment: Upto 10, (sorry i posted previous comment before I had finished typing it and had to edit)

Comment: @jimmywiddle - As long as `$this->relatedItems` isn't an associative array (having keys that aren't in sequence or strings as key), then you can use `$this->relatedItems[0]->extraFields->field1->value` outside the loop.

Comment: wow thanks so much magnus

Comment: @jimmywiddle - I added the comment in my answer below, so if it works for you, you can mark it as answered. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative 1**

As long as `$this->relatedItems` isn't an associative array (having keys that aren't in sequence or strings as key), then you can use this outside the loop:

```
$this->relatedItems[0]->extraFields->field1->value
```

**Alternative 2**

If the array keys in the `$this->relatedItems` are unpredictable/associative, you can use this code:

```
<?php 
$keys = [];
foreach($this->relatedItems as $key => $item): 
    $keys[] = $key;
?>

    <div class="column1"><?php echo $item->extraFields->field1->value; ?></div>
    <div class="column2"><?php echo $item->extraFields->field2->value; ?></div>
    <div class="column3"><?php echo $item->extraFields->field3->value; ?></div>

<?php 
endforeach; 
?>
```

This will create an array with all the keys (0-9, if you have 10 array items in the `$this->relatedItems`).

Then you can use this outside the loop:

```
$this->relatedItems[$keys[0]]->extraFields->field1->value
```

No need to copy all the values to new variables, since you already have them in your scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi dimensional arrays for storing values

Check out the example code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <?php
      $cars = array
  (
       array("Volvo",22,18),
       array("BMW",15,13),
       array("Saab",5,2),
       array("Land Rover",17,15)
  )    ;

 echo $cars[0][0].": In stock: ".$cars[0][1].", sold: ".$cars[0][2].".<br>";
 echo $cars[1][0].": In stock: ".$cars[1][1].", sold: ".$cars[1][2].".<br>";
 echo $cars[2][0].": In stock: ".$cars[2][1].", sold: ".$cars[2][2].".<br>";
 echo $cars[3][0].": In stock: ".$cars[3][1].", sold: ".$cars[3][2].".<br>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Like this

```
$items = array();
foreach($group_membership as $username) {
 $items[] = $username;
```

}

```
print_r($items);
```

Comment: Many thanks, although im wondering how I apply this to the example i gave? Any further help would be so much appreciated! Thanks again!